# Don't have same information exception in Angular Exception and in error method subscribe

Tags: angular, exception, subscribe, angular-http-interceptors

My back API return a custom exception when the system have a exception.

I can catch it info in `.subscribe(data => {}, error { // HERE })` and i see this in Chrome/F12/Network.

But i need obtainer this info in a Angular Interceptor for not write all error methods foreach subscribe.

**catchError() the Rxjs in a Angular interceptor NOT have this info.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your custom error message in the intercept this way:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            // code
        }

        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
    }))
}
```

Comment: Joel, please read the bold fragment. Not exist this info in catchError but yes in error method subscribe